# Safely extracting property from object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rxjs, destructuring

I have a this function:

```js
const someVar = someOtherVar.pipe(
        // filter((data) => data && !data.loading)   // Works
        filter(({ loading }) => !loading),  // Doesn't work if data is Null
);
```

Now, As mentioned in comments the commented code works in every case, but I want to make it work the second way. There could be the case that data is null. So, I will be getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'loading' of null

Is there any way to safely destructure JavaScript object?

Comment: Don't think so - default parameters won't take effect with null, and you can't destructure null

Comment: you could filter out the falsy values first, and then perform another filter which does the destructuring. But version 1 which checks `data` before also works

Comment: Maybe something like `const {loading} = data || {};`, but I think you're talking about destructuring in function parameters?

Comment: @Jason yes, in function parameters

Comment: `filter(data) => data && !data.loading)` only works if the expected outcome is a syntax error. ;-)

Comment: Yes, in my case it is working. As @CertainPerformance suggested, I think I have to go through with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is not an object, that's why you cannot safely destructure it :-) No, you cannot use destructuring here.

The closest-to-useful syntactical feature would be `data => !data?.loading` from the [*optional chaining* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining), but that's equivalent to `!(data && data.loading)` not `data && !data.loading`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is couple of options to make it work with your second option.

```
filter(x => x).filter(({ loading }) => !loading)
```

or

```
map(x => x || {}).filter(({ loading }) => !loading)
```

Both options may not be as efficient as your commented code, But these may give readability.